# How to retrieve Document Form field Values using C# Client

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign C# Client to retrieve an envelope's current recipient status including the values of document form fields.

Using REST API , I can retrieve the document form field values using the following url and setting the parameter include_tabs to true.
/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/recipients?include_tabs=true

How do I get the document form fields using the C# client?

Following method calls do not return the document form field values (no tabs information are returned.)

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
Recipients recips = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(accountId, envelopeId);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct API call to retrieve recipient tabs, instead of using the `ListRecipients()` call you need to make the `listTabs()` call, which has the following function signature:

```
Tabs ListTabs (string accountId, string envelopeId, string recipientId);
```

This is also why you should remember the `recipientId` values you set for your recipients when you add them to the envelope in the first place (i.e. so you can easily assign and retrieve their tab values later), otherwise you need to make an additional API call to retrieve that info.

Comment: Thank you! We can always query search_folders using REST API , get the envelope id and then retrieve recipientID. What is the correct API call that is equivalent to REST API call to get list of Envelopes. (/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/{search_folder})

Comment: Did my answer solve the main issue?  If so can you accept as the answer?  Regarding your latest question, it's the `ListStatusChanges()` function off of the `EnvelopesApi`.  Take a look at the `listEnvelopesTest()` recipe in the C# Recipes examples:  https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs